# Trigger to reject cosmos DB update from python

Tags: python, triggers, azure-cosmosdb

I have some code which updates a record in a cosmos DB container (see simplified snippet below). However there are other independent processes that also update the same record from other systems. In the example below if the state is a particular value, I would like the upsert_item() to be a no-op if the same record in the container already got updated to a particular "final" state. One way to solve it is to read the value before each update but that is a bit too expensive. Is there a simple way to make the upsert_item() turn into a no-op based on some server side trigger? Any pointers would be appreciated

```
client = CosmosClient(<end_pt>, <key>)
database_name = "cosmosdb"
container_name = "solar_system"
db_client = client.get_database_client(database_name)
db_container = db_client.get_container_client(container_name)
uid, planet, state = get_planetary_config()

# How can I make this following update a no-op depending on current state in the database?
json_data = {"id": str(uid), "planet": planet, "state": state}
db_container.upsert_item(body=json_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

As i know, the [cosmos db server side trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#triggers) does not meet your need.It is invoked to execute pre-function or post-function,not to judge whether the document meets some conditions.

So,update with specific conditions is not supported by Cosmos Db natively. You need to read the value and judge the condition before your update operations.